# Spring Security always redirects to Login Page even if Authentication is successful

Tags: spring-security

I'm trying to implement a Custom Authentication with Spring Security, the Authenticated Token is correctly returned from the Provider to the Filter. The "Successful Authentication" is triggered, but then it redirects to my "login" page even if I specified in the handler that I want a redirect to the "home" page.

Here is my SecurityConfig class :

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class DefaultSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }


    @Bean
    public DIDAuthenticationProvider didAuthenticationProvider(DIDUserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        return new DIDAuthenticationProvider(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean
    public DIDUserDetailsService didUserDetailsService(DIDUser... users) {
        return new DIDUserDetailsService(users);
    }

    @Bean
    public DIDAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authManager,
                                                        SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler,
                                                        SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler) {

        DIDAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter = new DIDAuthenticationFilter();

        authenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
        authenticationFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler);
        authenticationFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler);

        return authenticationFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler() {
        SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        authenticationSuccessHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/home");
        authenticationSuccessHandler.setAlwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl(true);

        return authenticationSuccessHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {
        SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler();
        authenticationFailureHandler.setDefaultFailureUrl("/login?error");
        authenticationFailureHandler.setUseForward(true);
        return authenticationFailureHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public DIDUser[] users() {
        DIDUser user = new DIDUser(
                "user",
                "did:test:123",
                "USER");
        return new DIDUser[]{user};
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http,
                                                          DIDAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter,
                                                          SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler
    ) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(form -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .logout(logout -> logout
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .anonymous(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .addFilterAt(authenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

My Filter :

```java
public class DIDAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    public static final String FORM_DID_KEY = "did";

    private static final AntPathRequestMatcher DEFAULT_ANT_PATH_REQUEST_MATCHER = new AntPathRequestMatcher("/did-login", "POST");

    public DIDAuthenticationFilter() {
        super(DEFAULT_ANT_PATH_REQUEST_MATCHER);
    }

    public DIDAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super(DEFAULT_ANT_PATH_REQUEST_MATCHER, authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        String did = request.getParameter(FORM_DID_KEY);
        if (!request.getMethod().equals("POST") || did == null || StringUtils.isEmptyOrWhitespace(did)) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Authentication method not supported: " + request.getMethod());
        }
        did = did.trim();
        DIDAuthenticationToken authRequest = DIDAuthenticationToken.unauthenticated(did, did);
        authRequest.setDetails(this.authenticationDetailsSource.buildDetails(request));
        return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
    }
}
```

My Provider :

```java
public class DIDAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider, InitializingBean, MessageSourceAware {

    private final DIDUserDetailsService users;

    protected MessageSourceAccessor messages = SpringSecurityMessageSource.getAccessor();

    public DIDAuthenticationProvider(DIDUserDetailsService users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String did = determineDID(authentication);

        DIDUser user = null;
        try {
            user = (DIDUser) retrieveUser(did);
        } catch (AuthenticationException ex) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException(this.messages
                    .getMessage("badCredentials", "Bad credentials"));
        }

        Assert.notNull(user, "retrieveUser returned null - a violation of the interface contract");

        Object principalToReturn = user;
        return createSuccessAuthentication(principalToReturn, authentication, user);
    }

    private UserDetails retrieveUser(String did) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            UserDetails loadedUser = this.users.loadUserByDid(did);

            if (loadedUser == null) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("UserDetailsService returned null");
            }
            return loadedUser;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("UserDetailsService returned null");
        }
    }

    private String determineDID(Authentication authentication) {
        return (authentication.getPrincipal() == null) ? "NONE_PROVIDED" : authentication.getName();
    }

    protected Authentication createSuccessAuthentication(Object principal, Authentication authentication,
                                                         UserDetails user) {
        DIDAuthenticationToken result = DIDAuthenticationToken.authenticated(principal, authentication.getCredentials(), user.getAuthorities());
        result.setDetails(authentication.getDetails());

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        Assert.notNull(this.messages, "A message source must be set");
        Assert.notNull(this.users, "A UserDetailsService must be set");
    }

    @Override
    public void setMessageSource(MessageSource messageSource) {
        this.messages = new MessageSourceAccessor(messageSource);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(DIDAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
```

Here is the DEBUG output after what should be a successful login :

```
2023-05-12T12:27:55.311+02:00 DEBUG 9680 --- [nio-9000-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /did-login
2023-05-12T12:27:55.312+02:00 DEBUG 9680 --- [nio-9000-exec-4] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to /home
2023-05-12T12:27:55.320+02:00 DEBUG 9680 --- [nio-9000-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /home
2023-05-12T12:27:55.324+02:00 DEBUG 9680 --- [nio-9000-exec-7] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:9000/home?continue to session
2023-05-12T12:27:55.324+02:00 DEBUG 9680 --- [nio-9000-exec-7] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:9000/login
2023-05-12T12:27:55.333+02:00 DEBUG 9680 --- [nio-9000-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login
2023-05-12T12:27:55.333+02:00 DEBUG 9680 --- [nio-9000-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /login
```

After the provider returns, the SecurityContext is correctly set by the filter... but it is like the user is not authenticated. I don't understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The solution as found by the asker was to add the following to the `DIDAuthenticationFilter` in their `SecurityConfig` class:

```
authenticationFilter.setSecurityContextRepository(new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository());
```